SpringBatch read inner list in xml with StaxEventItemReader
I have the next XML:
<parent>
  <child>
    <grandchild>
      <items>
        <item>VALUE1</item>
        <item>VALUE2</item>
        <item>VALUE3</item>
      </items>
    </granchild>
  <child>
</parent>

I want to read in my reader the content of the list items.
These are my classes:
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlRootElement(name = "parent")
public class Parent {

    @XmlElement(name = "child")
    private Child child;

    // getters / setters
}

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Child {

    @XmlElement(name = "grandchild")
    private Grandchild grandchild;

    // getters / setters
}

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Grandchild {

    @XmlElementWrapper(name = "items")
    @XmlElement(name = "item")
    private List<Item> items;

    // getters / setters
}

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Item {

    @XmlValue
    private String item;

    // getters / setters
}

With the next test I can print the content of the XML, so the marshaller and the classes seem to be ok:
@Test
public void test() throws JAXBException {

    final JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(Parent.class);
    final Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
    final File xmlFile = new File(XML_FILE);
    final Parent parent = (Parent) unmarshaller.unmarshal(xmlFile);  
    System.out.println(parent.getChild().getGrandchild().getItems().get(0).getItem());
}

This is my SpringBatch reader:
public class Reader extends StaxEventItemReader<Item> implements StepExecutionListener {

    public void Reader() {
        final Jaxb2Marshaller unmarshaller = new Jaxb2Marshaller();
        unmarshaller.setClassesToBeBound(Parent.class);
        this.setUnmarshaller(unmarshaller);
        this.setFragmentRootElementName("items");
    }
}

And I get an UnmarshalException saying that the expected element is "parent" and not "items".
Is it possible to achieve what I want to do?
